# How to left adjust and control spacing between values?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to left adjust and control placement of values. For example:

```
VAR          .21       74.7      0.68
VAR          0.42      71.3      1.3
```

values start at 13, 23, and 33 spaces from the very left side and all are left adjusted. I can control the start of values with ''.rjust() (such as '.21'.rjust(17)) but it right aligns text and the values won't start from 13 spaces. Please suggest how to put values at exact spacing with left adjustment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with standard python formatting and specifying left (`<`) or right (`>`) alignment along with a width.  See the python [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) on this subject.

Probably something like this

```
'{:<12}{:<10}{:<10}{:<10}'.format('VAR',num1,num2,num3)
```

Maybe you need to adjust the exact spacing instead of "10" above, but that should be a starting point.

Comment: one little hassle. I simply used '{:>11}'.format(2) and '{:>11}'.format(100) separately without 'VAR' at the start. It right align values pushing '100' to the left.

Comment: nevermind. I figured out that if I put an empty string with fixed width then '2' or '100' will start right where needed.

Answer (score 0):

[This `TextTable` class](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/texttable) supports easy table-formatting. You can define how cell-content is adjusted (among many other cool features).

Comment: Thanks but I need something from default installation.

Comment: You don't need to *install* it. It's a single file. Just *import* it.